# Set cookie inside iframe not working - Angular

Tags: angular, cookies, iframe, query-string

We have child site `www.child.com` which is currently `iframe` inside parent site `www.parent.com`.

From parent www.parent.com we pass some `query string` to `www.child.com` so that in www.child.com we can read the query string and set it to a cookie. On certain machines, in chrome the cookie is set successfully but on few machines, for some reason cookie is not set. And on one machine it worked earlier but past two days, the cookie is not set in that machine as well.

This works well in firefox.

```
www.parent.com
    -- www.child.com?token=<<sometoken>>
       set <<sometoken>> to a cookie in child.com
```

We are using Angular 7.x and aspnetboilerplate.

Comment: Have the exact same issue. The cookie is not set because it comes from a third party (child.com) and does not set `SameSite=None`, even though it's pratically first party due to being loaded from inside its own `iframe`.